# Tweet a pre-specified tweet with a single link

Tags: twitter

Is there a link format that a user can click that can open the Twitter site in a "create tweet" page, using a preset tweet?

Something like:

```
<a href="http://twitter.com/add?text=this is the tweet text" target="_blank">Click here</a>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you aware of their dev [docs](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/tweet-button)?
You can set the `text` property. For example:

```
https://twitter.com/share?text=Hello%20Stackoverflow
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes; see the [documentation](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/intents#tweet-intent).